# Statefulwidget is not refreshing ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm saving the data that is fetched from an API to the sqflite in flutter project, everything is working good, except that after clicking a raised button the data should be insert into the table and a new page should be open but there is no data unless I refresh that page so the data appear

As you can see, here is the code of the raised button:

```
 RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get Cities'),
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                 GetAllData.data.Getdata();
               });
                await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => StoreList()));
                setState(() {});
              },
            )
```

Inside the setState I'm calling a function Getdata to get the data from the sqflite, after it getting it the app should open a new page

And below is the code of the page which should show the data in a ListView:

```
class StoreList extends StatefulWidget { @override


 _StoreListState createState() => _StoreListState();}
class _StoreListState extends State<StoreList> {
@override void initState() {
super.initState();
setState(() {
  DatabaseProvider_API.db.getRoutes();
});}



@override


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Stores List'),
  ),
 body: FutureBuilder<List<Stores>>(
    future: DatabaseProvider_API.db.getStores(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      if(snapshot.data == null){
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),

        );
      }
 else {
        return ListView.separated(
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Divider();
          },
itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            String name = snapshot.data[index].sTORENAME;
            String name_ar = snapshot.data[index].cITY;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(name),
              subtitle:Text (name_ar),
              onTap: ()async{
                setState(() {
                });

                await
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => Category() ));
              },
            );
          },
        );
      }
    },
  ),
  floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {});
    },
    child: new Icon(Icons.update),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `await` keyword before evoke `GetAllData.data.GetData()`

```
              RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get Cities'),
              onPressed: () async {             
                  // await for new data to be inserted
                await GetAllData.data.Getdata();
                await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) => StoreList()));
                  setState(() {
                    dataFuture =  GetAllData.data.Getdata();
                  });
              },
            )
```

Comment: That worked actually, and its very logical to do so thank you